# Match values in array and replace with alternative

Tags: php, replace

How do you replace values in a string which match an entry in array with the same value but with a \ in front of it ?

```
$test = "Mike (D)";
$array('(',')','@','-');
```

As ( ) are in the array $test should equal `"Mike \(D\)";`

So basically replacing the item with item same item prefixed with \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$test      = "Mike (D)";
$find      = array('(',')','@','-');
$repalce   = array('\(','\)','\@','\-');

$newphrase = str_replace($find, $repalce, $test);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
addcslashes($test, "()@-");
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php

Comment: Why this give me `Mike \\(D\\)`?

Comment: It seems that depends of `php` or `server` configuration I think that adds backslashes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $needle) { 
    if(strpos($needle, $test) {
       str_replace($needle, '\\'.$needle, $test);
    }
 }
```

Or if you create an array with the replace strings, just use:

```
$array = array('(', ')', '@',...);
$replace = array('\(', '\)', '\@',...);
str_replace($array, $replace, $test);
```